# Kubernetes ConfigMap YAML into Terraform Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to convert the following `ConfigMap` yaml file ([link here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/opentsdb-bigtable/blob/master/configmaps/opentsdb-config.yaml)) into a [`kubernetes_config_map`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes/r/config_map.html) but am running into syntax errors when trying to define it.

In particular, I can't get around the dot notation inside the `opentsdb.conf` file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: opentsdb-config
data:
  opentsdb.conf: |
    google.bigtable.project.id = REPLACE_WITH_PROJECT
    google.bigtable.instance.id = REPLACE_WITH_INSTANCE
    google.bigtable.zone.id = REPLACE_WITH_ZONE
    hbase.client.connection.impl = com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase1_2.BigtableConnection
    google.bigtable.auth.service.account.enable = true

    tsd.network.port = 4242
    tsd.core.auto_create_metrics = true
    tsd.core.meta.enable_realtime_ts = true
    tsd.core.meta.enable_realtime_uid = true
    tsd.core.meta.enable_tsuid_tracking = true
    tsd.http.request.enable_chunked = true
    tsd.http.request.max_chunk = 131072
    tsd.storage.fix_duplicates = true
    tsd.storage.enable_compaction = false
    tsd.storage.max_tags = 12
    tsd.http.staticroot = /opentsdb/build/staticroot
    tsd.http.cachedir = /tmp/opentsdb
```

This is my current attempt that is erroring out on the `"opentsdb.conf"`

```
resource "kubernetes_config_map" "opentsdb" {
  metadata {
    name = "opentsdb-config",
    namespace = "dev"
  }

  data {
    "opentsdb.conf" = {
      google.bigtable.project.id = var.project_id,
      google.bigtable.instance.id = google_bigtable_instance.development-instance.name,
      google.bigtable.zone.id = var.zone,
      hbase.client.connection.impl = "com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase1_2.BigtableConnection",
      google.bigtable.auth.service.account.enable = true

      tsd.network.port = 4242
      tsd.core.auto_create_metrics = true
      tsd.core.meta.enable_realtime_ts = true
      tsd.core.meta.enable_realtime_uid = true
      tsd.core.meta.enable_tsuid_tracking = true
      tsd.http.request.enable_chunked = true
      tsd.http.request.max_chunk = 131072
      tsd.storage.fix_duplicates = true
      tsd.storage.enable_compaction = false
      tsd.storage.max_tags = 12
      tsd.http.staticroot = "/opentsdb/build/staticroot"
      tsd.http.cachedir = "/tmp/opentsdb"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to quote all the keys with dots in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue that I had is that I was trying to assign an object to a string literal.

I needed to use the `EOF` syntax as follows:

```
resource "kubernetes_config_map" "opentsdb" {
  metadata {
    name = "opentsdb-config"
    namespace = "dev"
  }

  data = {
    "opentsdb.conf" = <<EOF
google.bigtable.project.id = ${var.project_id}
google.bigtable.instance.id = ${var.bigtable_instance_id}
google.bigtable.zone.id = ${var.zone}
hbase.client.connection.impl = com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase1_2.BigtableConnection
google.bigtable.auth.service.account.enable = true

tsd.network.port = 4242
tsd.core.auto_create_metrics = true
tsd.core.meta.enable_realtime_ts = true
tsd.core.meta.enable_realtime_uid = true
tsd.core.meta.enable_tsuid_tracking = true
tsd.http.request.enable_chunked = true
tsd.http.request.max_chunk = 131072
tsd.storage.fix_duplicates = true
tsd.storage.enable_compaction = false
tsd.storage.max_tags = 12
tsd.http.staticroot = /opentsdb/build/staticroot
tsd.http.cachedir = /tmp/opentsdb
    EOF
  }
}
```

Comment: How did you call this resource from the pod/deployment?